# Negative eigenvalue for a periodic Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, eigenvalues, sturm-liouville-theory, periodic-functions

Let $f \in C^{\infty}([0, 2\pi])$ be a smooth function and consider the following periodic Sturm-Liouville problem:

$$\begin{cases} u''(x) + f(x)u(x) = - \lambda u(x) \\
u(0) = u(2\pi) \\
u'(0) = u'(2\pi)
\end{cases}$$

I would like to know if there are mild sufficient conditions on $f$ so that the above problem has a negative simple eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I already know that there are countably many eigenvalues for this problem.

Comment: Subtracting a negative constant from any $f$ that yields a simple eigenvalue is sufficient, but maybe you want to specify better what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dario i edited the post and added a new question.